# Query if Lead not modified in the current month?

Tags: soql, query, dynamic-soql

Is there a way to query if a `Lead` has not been modified in the current month by using `LastModifiedDate`?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply run SOQL query like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate 
FROM Lead 
WHERE CreatedDate <THIS_MONTH 
AND SystemModstamp <THIS_MONTH
```

> Better to use SystemModstamp instead of LastModifiedDate as it includes not just updates from the UI/API, but also updates from the system, such as changing picklist values.
>
> Secondly, you should always use SystemModStamp anyways, because it is indexed and therefore has better performance than LastModifiedDate (when using = or > comparisons though, the system covertly uses SystemModStamp when you use LastModifiedDate

Refer: [Force.com SOQL Performance Tips: LastModifiedDate vs SystemModStamp](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/11/force-com-soql-performance-tips-systemmodstamp-vs-lastmodifieddate-2.html)

Comment: @ngc, let me know if my answer solves your purpose and if so, then accept this so that others may find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

This one's pretty easy and you don't even need a dynamic query, just **[`Date Literals`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)**.

```
SELECT ... FROM Lead WHERE CreatdDate < THIS_MONTH
```